# Facebook & Twitter likes/shares as PHP variables

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I have looked through various answers here, but am still unable to figure it out.

Objective: to be able to have my php file output a simple line of text, such as "12 people have liked this website on Facebook and 16 people have twitted about it".

The numbers of course should come from facebook and twitter respectively.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these tutorials

[Twitter](http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/2010/01/07/learn-how-to-display-twitter-count-as-pure-text/) **edited**

[Facebook](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/how-to-display-facebook-fan-count-in-text/) **edited**

and they're both done in PHP

Comment: I don't **need** to use php, but i **do need** to output as plain text. I don't see how the APIs allow me to do it. Can you please help?